# how to return false and problematic row(python sudoku checker)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku

I'm having a problem returning both False, and the append number in the def checkit function. I'm not sure if I have miscoded the checkrow functions. It is able to return true when given a correctly solved Sudoku puzzle, but when we are to call an incorrect Sudoku puzzle, it is to return False, and provide the problematic row. Currently, it is only returning the problematic row, aka the location of what makes the puzzle fail, but not including false. any idea on how to make it so that it returns both?

```
import sys
from scanner import *

def createList(size):
    if size == 0: return []
    else:
        return [0] + createList(size -1)
def printGrid(gridlist):
    for row in gridlist:
       print (str(row)+"\n")
def rows(g):
    return len(g)
def cols(g):
    return len(g[0])

def printMatrix(g):
    for i in range(0,rows(g),1):
        for j in range(0,cols(g),1):
            print(g[i][j],end=' ')
        print('')
    print('')

def readinput(filename,grid):
    s = Scanner(filename)
    r = s.readtoken()
    while r != "":
        r = int(r)
        c = s.readint()
        v = s.readint()
        grid[r][c]=v
        r = s.readtoken()

def checkRows(g):
    for rows in g:
        numbersInRow = []
        for number in rows:
            if number != 0 and number in numbersInRow:
                return g.index(rows)
            else:
               numbersInRow.append(number)
    return True
def checkIt(g):
    checkRows(g)
    rowSuccess = checkRows(g)
    print(rowSuccess)
def main():
    grid = createList(9)
    for i in range(9):
        grid[i] = createList(9)
    readinput(sys.argv[1],grid)
    printMatrix(grid)
    checkIt(grid)
main()
```

Comment: What about returning a tuple `return False, g.index(rows)`?

Comment: @RubenBermudez Sorry, didn't mean to be a ninja. Want me to delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can return both of them:

```
def checkRows(g):
    for rows in g:
        numbersInRow = []
        for number in rows:
            if number != 0 and number in numbersInRow:
                return g.index(rows), False
            else:
               numbersInRow.append(number)
```

And to read it:

```
problematic_row, result = checkRows(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

`return False, g.index(rows)` will return two values as a tuple.